# synchronization works - no contacts

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, iphone

Synchronization worked fine for me until the adressbook of my Idevice crashed today.
Now it's fixed and the uploading of my contacts seems to work. Anyway the contacts do not appear in ubuntuone. Reinstalling the app or relogging doesnt matter.

Comment: I think you will get the best results by contacting the UbuntuOne [support](https://one.ubuntu.com/support/).
If they solve your problem please post the solution here so that other people with the same problem can find it.

Comment: quote ubuntuone support:
"Unfortunately, we're unable to debug this type
of mobile contacts sync issue so I processed a full refund for you" I'll keep trying to get a solution and in case of success I'll post it here

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they ended ubuntu one contacts sync mobile support. 
See [this](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2011/05/09/some-changes-to-contacts-2/) canonical blog post.

There's an upcoming change / revamp in the contacts system, including google contacts sync.